# How to display ProgressBar with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have link for picture and I use Picasso for download and show it. Can I display ProgressBar to show that picture is loading?

here is my code:

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
         .load(MYurl.BASE_URL + "/" + getItem(position).getImgThumb())
         .into(new Target() {
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         finalViewHolder.asanaImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to start your progress bar before you load the image with Picasso. later you can dismiss it in loaded or failed callbacks.

```
//start progressbar here
Picasso.with(mContext)
         .load(MYurl.BASE_URL + "/" + getItem(position).getImgThumb())
         .into(new Target() {
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
         finalViewHolder.asanaImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         //stop progressbar here
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
        //stop progressbar here
}

@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
}
});
```